# Replace values in Column without creating new column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to modify one of my queries to select all values in the db, but also replace all values that are either NULL or "-" in the column "RA" with the value "No RA".

```
    Select *,
    IF(RA IS NULL OR RA='-', 'No RA', RA)
    from dbname
```

When I do the above command, it's replacing the values but it replaces them in a newly created column called "IF(RA IS NULL OR RA='-', 'No RA', RA)". How can I do by only modifying the existing RA column?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try to use REPLACE and CASE of MYSQL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just don't use select * but use a proper select using explicit column name for all the columns you need

```
 Select  IF(RA IS NULL OR RA='-', 'No RA', RA) RA, col2, col3 

    from dbname
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate the columns that you want to `select`, and alias the compted expression:

```
select
    co11,
    col2,
    ..., -- other columns to return (excepted "ra")
    case when ra is null or ra = '-' then 'No RA' else ra end ra
from dbname
```